# Sum into aggregate rows based on duplicate column value

Tags: excel

I have a large data set that looks something like this:

```
239617920   0   1   1   1
239617917   0   1   1   1
239617911   1   1   0   1
239617911   1   0   0   1
239617890   0   0   0   1
239617885   1   1   0   1
```

For each row, I want to be able to sum up the values of columns B, C, D, and E if column A values are equal, into one aggregate row.
Therefore, I want my output to be

```
239617920   0   1   1   1
239617917   0   1   1   1
239617911   2   1   0   2
239617890   0   0   0   1
239617885   1   1   0   1
```

Since I have `239617911` listed twice.

Is there a way to do this in excel?

Comment: This is great usecase for a pivot table. Just dump the first column into the `Rows` and the remaining four columns into the `Values`. Make sure that the four `value` columns are set to `SUM` instead of `Count`

Comment: I absolutely agree with JNevill. Pivot table is the solution for your need if you want to do it through excel else you can write a custom code in VBA to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot tables are great for this, but it's not difficult to do the same thing using formulas.

Assuming your data starts in cell A2, enter the following in G2, and copy down as many rows as needed:

```
=SMALL(A:A,COUNTIF(A:A,"<="&G1)+1)
```

[image]

Enter the following in cell H2, and copy to all other summary cells:

```
=SUMIF($A:$A,$G2,B:B)
```

[image]